# Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code : 404

Tags: facebook, httpresponse

I have fixing this problem for many nights already....
Please help!

I have changed a lot of header to try. And I did put og:url and og:title on the html code of the page...
But the reports said I didn't do it....

The page cannot scraped....

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmaj7th.com%2F

Is it something wrong which I don't know? Please help me!

Comment: Probably not related to this, but your page is trying to load two JS files and failing. jquery-1.4.3.min.js and common.js